# locals blank in Jade

Tags: node.js, express, pug, locals

I have a file which is setup to handle a file and set the title and locals variables for my jade template.

```
module.exports = {
handle_index : function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'Home',
        locals: {name: 'User Name'}      
    });
}
};
```

My jade template:

```
!!!5
head
  title= title
body
  div 
    p The User Name:
    p #{locals.name}
    p Is Valid
```

The resulting HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head><title>Home</title></head>
<body>
<div>
<p>The User Name:</p>
<p></p>
<p>Is Valid</p>
</div>
</body>
```

The `<p>` tag is generated and blank.  I've also tried `=name` and the same result except with no `<p>` tag at all.

I'm not sure why this isn't made available to the Jade template, however title is showing that everything appears connected correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  Wasn't realizing everything was setup correctly, just had an object with nothing in it!

```
handle_index : function(req, res) {
    var local = {name : "User Name"};
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'Home',
        locals : local  
    });
}
};
```

With this Jade:

```
!!!5
head
  title= title
body
  div 
    p The User Name:
    p #{locals.name}
    p Is Valid
```

Did the trick.  This is why coding for too long can be bad and an example of how a good nights rest will let you see the obvious things the next morning!